# Expressing mixed feeling of both scared and sad

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, expressions

Sometime when I shout at my kids, they get scared and also they get sad. How do express this mixed feeling in writing? I wrote as below where Tommy refers my son. Is that the correct way?

> Tommy, scared, looked at me sadly.

Comment: Okay Persian Cat, but my question whether my sentence is correct and whether its means the mixed feeling correctly?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your sentence grammatically- whether it conveys the emotions you wish to convey is a question that cannot be answered definitively.  I might say Tommy was "scared and hurt" As in- his feelings were hurt.

Comment: I meant the same as Jim said. :)

Answer (score 1):

One possible combination of the words you specified is *upset*.

I *upset* Tommy with my shouting.